# How to divide between rows in one table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in Postgres with a table like this:

```
mon   yyyy   weather
Apr   2014   78.45
Apr   2015   77.32
May   2014   79.56
May   2015   78.43
```

I would like to be able to query some results, ordered by "mon", where the `weather` column values are divided according to year-on-year by month.

In other words I want to query weather where Apr 2015 is divided by Apr 2014.

However, I would like to write the query in such a way that I do not have to specify month or year, and the query automatically divides `weather` values according to: Apr 2015/Apr 2014, then May 2014/May 2014 without having to key in every month and every year, which is laborious.

I have the following code, but this expands columns which is not what I want:

```
select (select "Weather" from yoy 
        where mon = 'Apr' and yyyy = '2015'
     )/(select "American" from yoy 
        where mon = 'Apr' and yyyy = '2014'
     ) as "weather_apr",
     (select "Weather" from yoy 
      where mon = 'May' and yyyy = '2015'
     )/(select "Weather" from yoy 
        where mon = 'May' and yyyy = '2014'
     ) as "weather_may",
from yoy;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is the right scenario to take advantage of analytical [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html). Here the magic without joins:

```
SELECT yyyy,       
       weather,
       mon,
       lead( weather ) over (partition by mon order by mon, yyyy desc),
       weather / lead( weather ) over (partition by mon order by mon, yyyy desc)
FROM joy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a self join like in the below example:

```
SELECT j1."yyyy" As year,
       j2."yyyy" As next_year,
       j1."mon",
       j1."weather",
       j2."weather" As "weather from next year",
       j1."weather"::float / j2."weather" As divide
FROM joy j1
JOIN joy j2 
ON j1."yyyy" = j2."yyyy" - 1 AND j1."mon" = j2."mon"
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e02ec/1

Answer (score 0):

I find conditional aggregation can be quite useful for this type of query:

```
select mon,
       max(case when yyyy = 2014 then weather end) as weather_2014,
       max(case when yyyy = 2015 then weather end) as weather_2015,
       (max(case when yyyy = 2015 then weather end) /
        max(case when yyyy = 2014 then weather end)
       ) as ratio
from yoy
group by mon
```

This assumes that you want the rows reduced to one per month.  To get the previous value, just use `lag()`:

```
select yoy.*,
       lag(weather) over (partition by month order by year) as prev_weather
from yoy;
```